# Rust simd: Cannot set `RUSTC_BOOTSTRAP=1` from build script of `simd v0.2.4`

Tags: rust, simd, rust-cargo

I'm learning to use SIMD in my program, but Carbo build fails after adding `simd = "0.2.4"` to `Cargo.toml`'s dependencies (error says Cannot set `RUSTC_BOOTSTRAP=1` from build script of `simd v0.2.4`.):

```
# Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "rust-simd"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
simd = "0.2.4"
```

```
// main.rs
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

How do I fix it to use SIMD?

Comment: Do you use nightly?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman No. didn't even know what is nightly. Is it like a  testing (unstable) version?

Comment: Yes, [Channels - The rustup book](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/concepts/channels.html).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/hsivonen/simd

> *This crate no londer builds as of Rust 1.33 nightly* due to the [removal of compiler features](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/57416) that this crates depends on. See the [`packed_simd`](https://crates.io/crates/packed_simd) crate instead.

Also, even when worked, it required nightly Rust.

Although [`packed_simd` also warns](https://github.com/rust-lang/packed_simd) (haven't checked that):

> The original maintainer is out of contact, and the new maintainers (the Portable SIMD Project Group) do not have the appropriate crates.io permissions to issue updates.
>
> We are aware that the version available on crates.io is currently broken, and will not build.

Since both crates require nightly anyway, you may use [`std::simd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/simd/) (https://github.com/rust-lang/portable-simd).

Comment: I struggle to find even one working hello world for Rust-SIMD

Comment: @Rahn Indeed the SIMD in std assumes familiarity with the concepts. But there is some example on the repository.